# Insert an object with Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an `Object` like this:

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private ArrayList<String> trade;
}
```

How could I add the Item into my database? I don't know the size of `trade`, because it can be updated at any time (only increased, not decreased).

Comment: have you tried using `varchar` for the following...

Comment: I didn't get the question. make it more understandable, What do you want to add into the database? the entire Item Object or every string in the trade list?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the first answer [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781708/getting-sqlite-database-and-storing-it-in-an-array-of-objects). they have also used variable size arraylist.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a One-to-Many relationship which is common in databases. I would do this as two tables:

The first table has a row for each of your objects with a unique ID, the name and the type. The second table would have a row for each item in trade, with a foreign key corresponding to the ID of the object in the first table. Something like this:

**Table 1:**

```
Id  | Name    | Type

1    Object1    SomeType
2    Object2    SomeOtherType
```

**Table 2:**

```
Id  | Foreign Key |   Trade
1     1               Trade belonging to Object1
2     1               Another trade belonging to Object1
3     2               Trade belonging to Object2
4     1               A recently added trade belonging to Object1
```

Consider taking a primer in SQL. [Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-sql)'s isn't a bad place to start.