# Replacing json retrieval with database retrieval in project

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-tv, leanback

Apologies if I'm not providing enough information here, I'm new to android/java and am learning by combining elements of various example projects.

I have a working `VerticalGridFragment` page for an Android TV project (using leanback) that loads album cover art and details in columns and rows. It borrows heavily from the [googlesamples example on github](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/MainFragment.java).

Using a test `music_database_proto.json` file in the format of:

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "type": "GRID_SQUARE",
      "title": "Around the World in a Day",
      "artist": "Prince and the Revolution",
      "description": "Prince and the Revolution",
      "groupType": 0,
      "tagID": 0,
      "localImageResource": "food_01"
    }
}
```

I can then load this using a `createRows()` function (from the same sample project) using:

```
PresenterSelector cardPresenterSelector = new CardPresenterSelector(getActivity());
mAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenterSelector);
String json = Utils.inputStreamToString(getResources().
    openRawResource(R.raw.music_database_proto));
CardRow row = new Gson().fromJson(json, CardRow.class);
mAdapter.addAll(0, row.getCards());
```

Which uses the sample projects classes of [CardRow.class](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/models/CardRow.java), [Card.class](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/models/Card.java) and their various supporting classes in the example.

I've implemented an `SQLite` database that successfully initiates and I can call various results in the Logs of Android Studio. I don't know where to start with inserting results from the database as `Cards` that I can load into the `VerticalGridFragment`, replacing the function of the `json` file?

I thought it would be as simple as creating a `List<Card>` from database results and adding this to `mAdapter` using `mAdapter.addAll`. However, I've had little luck in implementing a `List` of `Card` objects using iterating code. Desperately, I thought I should turn database results into a `json` string and feed them into the existing code I showed above?

Any help appreciated. The database is as basic as a recreation of the json variables and can be adjusted to suit.

Comment: You are looking for a simple solution to implement  offline storage mechanism to store all your JSON classes  in to ur database right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by `However, I've had little luck in implementing a List of Card objects using iterating code.`? If you're calling `mAdapter.addAll(0, cards)` with a list of cards, it should work as you desire.

Are you having difficulty extracting the list of cards from your SQLite database? You can rely on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781708/getting-sqlite-database-and-storing-it-in-an-array-of-objects) which has the following answer. I've modified it slightly to be about `Card.class`. You'll also need to add a constructor to the `Card` object since they provided it to you assuming you'd use `@SerializedName` to initialize it. The below example assumes you've added a constructor that looks like `public Card(String title, String description)`.

```
List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();
database = openOrCreateDatabase("your_db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
if(database!=null)
{
    c= database.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.isAfterLast()==false)
    {
        Card card = new Card(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")),
                             c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")));
        cardsList.add(card);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

}
database.close();
c.close();
```

The example is really just a starting point, but they encourage you to customize any of those classes within the sample to better fit your needs.

I also like that you're trying to learn SQLite since it's a piece of Android (and mobile development in general) that is good to be familiar with. You can also use a library like [Stetho by Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) to make sure your SQLite tables actually contain the correct data. It makes debugging a little easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What I meant is that my familiarity with basic PHP, javascript and the fundamentals of conditional programming, variables and values is still leaving me scratching my head with some of the Android examples I pointed to. For example, if I look through `Card.java` class and think I can make a new card object by referencing it, I'll inevitably get a compilation error. For a more precise example, if I use your code above, the line `Card card = new Card(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"))...` produces `Card() in Card cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

Comment: Okay I understand now. To instantiate an object (and populate its fields), you can use a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). The `Card` class they provide can only instantiate its fields through json at this point. So you'll need to add a new "constructor" to the Card class which takes the fields you'd like to populate as arguments. Something like `public Card(String title, String description)`. That constructor isn't there yet so you'll need to add it (that's why you're getting that compile error). Please let me know if that works.

Comment: Ah, I was on the right track then. I figured it was an issue with the current `Card` class showing various serialized fields when I was trying to give it Strings. It was the best reading of the error I could make.
I'm going to go off and do some research on this now, many thanks for the advice, and I'll definitely post back. I just put together some crude code based on what you said and a little reading. It seems too simple to work so I imagine I'll be at this a bit longer. Thanks again.

Comment: Well call me surprised, it's 75% worked and I think I can see where to go to get it to 100%. I need to look in the supporting classes and in the `Card` class itself to get the rest of the variables that it's currently crashing without. I added the following to the `Card` class to test:
`public Card(String dbTitle, String dbArtist) {
        mTitle = dbTitle;
        mArtist = dbArtist;
        mType = Type.GRID_SQUARE;
        mTagID = "1.jpg";
    };`
Thanks again. Having a go at a question that wasn't entirely concise or legible is much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it's coming together. Yeah, the @SerializedName annotation is exclusively for initializing a class with JSON, but there are a few other ways you can initialize the fields in Java (constructors and getters/setters).
You can find where the variables causing the crashes are used by right clicking the "getter" and selecting "Find Usages". They're most likely required by the [ImagePresenter](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/presenters/ImageCardViewPresenter.java)

Answer (score 1):

[Realm for android](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) would be your best choice.

Its **easy to  use** and its **faster than SQLite**.
 And its just few lines of code needed to get things started. Please check it out. I'm recently tunred out to be Realm Evangelist(not officially) after falling in love with it. Only setback would be getting used fluent interface based Queries and it happens only if your queries are too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm brand new to Android (and pretty much any software development) so I've a feeling it would be wise not to skip familiarity with SQLite. That said, I've some familiarity with MySQL with PHP and Android and SQLite feel like an absolute pain compared to it.